# Custom new command in math mode with two alternative outputs depending on input arguments

Tags: macros, ifthenelse

I have written some custom commands to use inside mathmode.
The command basically corrects the style of the left side sub and superscript. It decides which script is the longest and right-justify the shortest one.
The command works sometimes but sometimes fails, giving an error message in the log file.

I attached a basic example of my .tex document and output .pdf

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    
    \newlength{\ArgOne}
    \newlength{\ArgTwo}
    
    
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\stripunit}[1]{\strip@pt#1}
    \makeatother
        
    \newcommand{\Tes}[5]{

\settowidth{\ArgOne}{#2}    \settowidth{\ArgTwo}{#3}    
        \ifdim \stripunit{\ArgOne} pt>\stripunit{\ArgTwo} pt
        {}_{#2}^{\mathmakebox[\stripunit{\ArgOne} pt]{\hfill#3}}#1_{#4}^{#5}
        \else
        {}_{\mathmakebox[\stripunit{\ArgTwo} pt-4pt]{\hfill#2}}^{#3}#1_{#4}^{#5}
        \fi 
    }
        
    \begin{document}
    Regular expressions:
    
    ${}_{j+1}^{k}{K}_{l}^{m}$\;\;\;\;\;${}_{j}^{k+1}{K}_{l}^{m}$
    
    Using custom command:
    
    $\Tes{K}{j+1}{k}{l}{m}$\;\;\;\;\;$\Tes{K}{j}{k+1}{l}{m}$
    
        
    \end{document}
```

this is my output pdf when no errors

[image]

when compilation fails I get the message:

> Missing $ inserted line #(1st line where my command is used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the empty line (which will be converted into a `\par`) at the beginning of `\Tes`:

```tex
\newcommand{\Tes}[5]{

  \settowidth{\ArgOne}{#2}
  % ...
}
```

Also there's no need to firstly strip `pt` then add it back.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\ArgOne}
\newlength{\ArgTwo}
    
\newcommand{\Tes}[5]{
  \settowidth{\ArgOne}{#2}
  \settowidth{\ArgTwo}{#3}    
  \ifdim\ArgOne>\ArgTwo
    {}_{#2}^{\mathmakebox[\ArgOne]{\hfill#3}}#1_{#4}^{#5}
  \else
    {}_{\mathmakebox[\ArgTwo-4pt]{\hfill#2}}^{#3}#1_{#4}^{#5}
  \fi
}
    
\begin{document}
Regular expressions:

${}_{j+1}^{k}{K}_{l}^{m}$\;\;\;\;\;${}_{j}^{k+1}{K}_{l}^{m}$
\bigskip

Using custom command:

$\Tes{K}{j+1}{k}{l}{m}$\;\;\;\;\;$\Tes{K}{j}{k+1}{l}{m}$
   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, I keep forgetting the empty lines create issues in math mode.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a macro `\Tes` which copies the same "slant" of the right subscripts to the left side too.

```
\def\Tes#1#2#3#4#5{
   \setbox0=\hbox{$#1_x$}
   \setbox1=\hbox{$#1_x^x$}
   \dimen1=\wd1 \advance\dimen1 by-\wd0
   \setbox0=\hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}
   \setbox1=\hbox{$\scriptstyle#3$}
   \dimen0=\wd0
   \ifdim\wd1>\wd0 \dimen0=\wd1 \fi
   {}_{\hbox to\dimen0{\hss \box0}}^{\hbox to\dimen0{\hss \box1\kern-\dimen1}}
   #1_{#4}^{#5}
}

$\Tes{K}{j+1}{k}{l}{m}$

\bye
```

[image: Kk]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're stripping `pt` and then add it back. I can't understand the `-4pt` either.

Just measure the objects and decide which one is longer. I also add phantoms to set the superscripts and the subscripts at the same height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\tessup}
\newlength{\tessub}

\newcommand{\Tes}[5]{%
  \settowidth{\tessub}{$\scriptstyle#2$}%
  \settowidth{\tessup}{$\scriptstyle#3$}%
  \ifdim\tessup>\tessub
    \setlength{\tessub}{\tessup}%
  \fi
  \vphantom{#1}_{\mathmakebox[\tessub][r]{#2\vphantom{#4}}}%
    ^{\mathmakebox[\tessub][r]{#3\vphantom{#5}}}%
  {#1}_{#4\vphantom{#2}}^{#5\vphantom{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\Tes{K}{j+1}{k}{l}{m}$

$\Tes{K}{j}{k+1}{l}{m}$

$\Tes{\hat{K}}{j}{k+1}{l}{m}$

\end{document}
```

[image]